# Avoid simultaneous job modifications in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, configuration, locking, dsl

I am using the Jenkins Job DSL Plugin to create template jobs.

There is a problem when two or more users are modifying the same template job (or any other job) simultaneously. The configuration of the last user to save or apply the modifications are registered and the modifications of the other user are removed because the two users were working on the same configuration version.

For example: Recently, I had to add a user to the global authorization matrix in a template job. I did that and i saved and build it. However, another user was modifying the same template job all day and he saved it at the end of the day and my changes were removed.

Is there a way to avoid this simultaneous job modifications by locking the configuration of a job for other users when that user is currently updating it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not currently available in core.

[Full Answer](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jenkinsci-users/PDh22OZdLzA)